# The calculator performs the operations in correct order after all

Tags: applications, calculator

I was wrong. I checked several sources, including rules for javascript operand calculation rules. The misconception arises because the number beside the parantheses is not bound to the parenthetical expression, which is to be treated as a number, making the equation 3 numbers worked from left to right without any add-sub to deal with. Multiple sources to cite but here is one at bottom of post.

Rule 1: First perform any calculations inside parentheses
(2=1)=3
Rule 2: Next perform all multiplications and divisions, working from left to right.
6/2*3 = 9.
Rule 3: Lastly, perform all additions and subtractions, working from left to right.

http://www.mathgoodies.com/les.../vol7/order_operations.html
[image: Android calculator performs operations correctly]

Comment: So, what is your question? "Why it's like that? What should I do?" If that's your question, try experimenting using different calculators from Play Store (there are 1000s of calc apps). Use the one that gives you the right answer that you seek.. Also, give this a read: **[`A Calculation Conundrum`](http://web.archive.org/web/20161119062059/www.mathmagical.co.uk/Mathematics/CalcPuz.html)**

Comment: @GokulNC: after answering, saw your comment +1. This particular exiample seems to be popular !

Answer (score 2):

This evaluates as I expect.

1. Parentheses

   6 / 2 (2 + 1) = 6 / 2 (3)
2. Left to right multiplication and division

   6 / 2 (3) = 3 (3) = 9

The original expression is equivalent to 6 / 2 * (2+1). This is not equivalent to 6 / (2 * (2+1)) = 1.